# DEFINE A LEVEL OF LOGS IN DATASTAGE

Tags: websphere, datastage

when I want to see the logs of a datastage job it gave me only the logs with the info level logs 
I want to define a new level to see the logs please 
Any help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add more information - this is not enough - read the stackoverflow information how to ask questions and give examples

Comment: Hi @MichaelTiefenbacher thank you for your reply let me explain the problem (we have different level of logs info - error -warning ... ) the default level in the logs for datastage is info there is a way i can change the default level to show also the warnings for example ?

Answer (score 0):

Datastage knows three level of log entries - as you mentioned already:

- Info
- Warning
- Error

They will be shown if they appear - so you do not have to do anything for it (as your question asumes)

You can ["demote" a warning](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418587) to an informational message or promote one i.e. from an information to a warning.

EDIT: 
To do this you can define so called [Messgae Handlers](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418587) 
his can be done on Job level or Project level (or Runtime handler) 
In DataStage Director you eed to follow these steps: Menu - Tools - Message Handler Management
There are lots of descriptions out there - just search for DataStage Message Handler

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information can you give me more informations about how to demote a warning and if there is any tutorial that can help me please ??